# Exact details of how Empty works in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I'm new to VBScript and rather perplexed as to why the following code works:

```
set Adapters = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")

for each Nic in Adapters
    if Nic.IPEnabled then
        MsgBox "IP Address: " & Nic.IPAddress(asdf), 4160, "IP Address"
    end if
next
```

When the variable `asdf` is undefined, it works. If I define `asdf` to an invalid index (e.g. -1 or 4), I get an invalid index error.

I thought: Perhaps undefined variables default to 0 in VBS? Nope, I tried to print it and nothing is written.

Where is the functionality of passing an undefined variable as an array index returning the first item in the array documented? What are some other, similar oddities I may run into while programming in VBScript?

**Edit:** Some things I've discovered:

- Undefined variables are equal to `Empty` by default in VBScript
- `Empty = 0` is true
- `Nic.IPAddress(Empty)` also returns the first element of the array
- `MsgBox 0` will print `0`, while `MsgBox Empty` will print nothing

I'm still having trouble finding any documentation stating that array indexing handles `Empty` quietly by returning the first element, explaining why it is equivalent to but printed differently from 0, and what other constructs handle `Empty` parameters (and what they do as a result).

Comment: can't you do: `Nic.IPAddress(asdf==null?0:asdf)`? or something similar

Comment: For one, that doesn't work. Second, even if it did, it doesn't explain why the code runs the way it is.

Comment: Does the code return the first item? Or is it not doing that and you are trying to make it happen?

Comment: `why the following code works`, it is returning the first element. Try it yourself.

Comment: you also said "If the value is an invalid index, I get an invalid index error."

Comment: Yes, if I set `asdf = -1` I get invalid index. However, undefined variables **are not** invalid indexes. Why that is so is my question. Edited that part for clarity.

Comment: If you're going to downvote my question, please leave a comment why. Just because the question is hard to answer, doesn't make it a bad question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The undefined variable is `Empty` and returning the `Empty` index of an array will also return the `0` index.

In the `IPAddress` array, there are two indexes, a `0` and a `1`.

So this will have the same effect as your code:
`MsgBox "IP Address: " & Nic.IPAddress(0), 4160, "IP Address"`
And
`MsgBox "IP Address: " & Nic.IPAddress(Empty), 4160, "IP Address"`

And this will give you the IPv6 addresses:
`MsgBox "IP Address: " & Nic.IPAddress(1), 4160, "IP Address"`

Also, this will return both indexes of the array:
`WScript.Echo Join(Nic.IPAddress,",")`

Also, consider this example,
`arr = Array("first","second","third")`
`WScript.Echo arr(Empty)`

The output here will be `first`

See this post for VBScript Data Types:
"Empty : Variant is uninitialized. Value is 0 for numeric variables or a zero-length string ("") for string variables.`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: As per my edit I've discovered this. I still have not found any documentation that says that array indexing quietly handles `Empty` parameters by returning the first element, where else `Empty` is silently handled instead of throwing an error, or why `Empty` is equal to 0 but doesn't display 0 when printed.

Comment: It's because VBScript is a very simple language.  
See this post for VBScript Data Types:  
"Empty: Variant is uninitialized. Value is 0 for numeric variables or a zero-length string ("") for string variables.`  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: Thank you! That explains exactly what is going on here. Please put that link and comment in your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to Langstrom for providing this:
"Empty: Variant is uninitialized. Value is 0 for numeric variables or a zero-length string ("") for string variables."

**Empty:**

`Nic.IPAddress(asdf)` treats the parameter as an int, and `CInt(Empty)` is equal to `0`, the index of the first element of the array.

`MsgBox asdf` treats the parameter as a string, and `CStr(Empty)` returns an empty string.

Any function that expects an integer and for which `0` is a valid value will work exactly the same as if `0` had been passed when called with an `Empty` parameter.

When comparing `Empty = 0`, `Empty` is treated as an integer because it being compared to an integer, so the expression is true.

When comparing `Empty = "0"`, `Empty` is treated as a string, and so the expression is false. Therefore, `Empty = ""` is true.

**Null:**

Also, it is worth mentioning that `Null` is not equal to anything, including itself. `Null = Null` is false.